# How to extract the strings between the delimiters '<' and '>' from the string "Rahul<is>an<entrepreneur>"?

Tags: java, string

How to extract the strings between the delimiters '<' and '>' from the string

```
 “Rahul<is>an<entrepreneur>”
```

I tried using substring() method, but I could only extract one string out of the primary string. How to loop this and get all the strings between the delimiters from the primary string

Comment: can you post the code that you've tried

Comment: Hi. Could you post your code snippet so one could see what you have tried so far. For your question exist different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Pattern` and `Matcher` for pattern lookup. For example, see code below:

```
String STR = "Rahul<is>an<entrepreneur>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(STR);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.start() + " " + matcher.end() + " " + matcher.group());
        }
```

Output of above will give you start and end indexes and group substring:

```
5 9 <is>
11 25 <entrepreneur>
```

More specifically if you just want the strings, you can get string between the group start and end indexes.

> STR.substring(matcher.start() + 1, matcher.end() - 1);

This gives you only the matching strings.

Comment: well explained.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
    String str = "Rahul<is>an<entrepreneur>";
    String[] tempStr = str.split("<");

    for (String st : tempStr) {
        if (st.contains(">")) {
            int index = st.indexOf('>');
            System.out.println(st.substring(0, index));
        }

    }
```

Output:
is
entrepreneur